# Login behaviour when data warehouse is down

Tags: data-warehouse

I need a clarification on the behaviour of login to application when data warehouse is down.

What should be the behaviour of the application, should it leave user to login and give a message saying data warehouse is down or it should not at all leave user to login.

Please clarify.

Thanks,
RJ

Answer (score 0):

It should give a message to the user that currently the data warehouse is down. The user does not unnecessarily waste time attempting login again and again. If possible, the user should be prompted as to when the data warehouse will be up.

Comment: Thank you Nirman, So user should be able to login to application and when data warehouse is up user should be notified saying data warehouse is up and ready to use.